# Checking if Point is inside a GeoJson polygon using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a list of points stored in my database, in a text format.

```
lat | long
"-73.88110000007934", "40.817699999744555"
"-73.92675000057572","40.81840599962764"
"-73.883573184", "40.751662187"
```

I have a geojson file similar to this one:

```
d= { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -73.869424572841766, 40.74915687096788 ], [ -73.891431299772762, 40.74684466041932 ], [ -73.895071432408585, 40.746465470812154 ], [ -73.896187378678206, 40.748509425180877 ], [ -73.895839541851402, 40.74854687570604 ], [ -73.895252427743969, 40.748306609450246 ], [ -73.896540410855621, 40.750541998143589 ], [ -73.895798686138292, 40.750619721332619 ], [ -73.896522306614344, 40.754388796109033 ], [ -73.881648121884808, 40.755951617041873 ], [ -73.872218558824784, 40.756943248067479 ], [ -73.871679923567925, 40.753987174396038 ], [ -73.872070465138904, 40.753862007052064 ], [ -73.869424572841766, 40.74915687096788 ] ] ] }
```

When I tried to use

```
ST_Within('POINT(-73.883573184, 40.751662187)' 
    ,
    ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(d) 
)
```

Based on what I have understood, they have the same object (geom), but I couldn't succeed in converting/CASTing objects, HOW CAN I do this the right way ?

Comment: What is the error message? What is your full query? What is the result of just doing `SELECT ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(d)`? Also, you should convert your points stored as text to actual 2D geometry.

Comment: You have a comma in your POINT WKT. It should be `'POINT(-73.883573184 40.751662187)'`

Answer (score 3):

You must convert point coordinates to geometry

```
SELECT ST_Within(St_GeomFromText('POINT(-73.883573184  40.751662187)'), ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(d));
```